# Why is a rigid rotation on a torus ergodic?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I have the exercise to show that a rigid rotation on a torus is ergodic given that $\langle \omega , j \rangle \notin \mathbb{Z}$ for all $j \in \mathbb{Z}^n$.

I tried showing that the for all integrable functions $f$ the fact $f(\varphi(x))=f(x)$ implies that $f$ is constant almost everywhere. But that's all I have so far.

Thanks for your help.

Here you can find the exercise:
[image: Here you can find the exercise]

Comment: Maybe for clarification the rotation is given by $\varphi(x) =(x_1*e^{2\pi*i*\alpha_1},x_2*e^{2\pi*i*\alpha_2},\dots,x_n*e^{2\pi*i*\alpha_n})$